# Can you put a span to the center in css?

Tags: html, css

I am wondering, is there a way you can make the span tag move into the center using css?

I need to ask this question because whenever I put `text-align` in the span, it doesn't work.

Html

```
<span>
This is span.
</span>`
```

Css

```
span {
text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: I also really need to use the span tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just horizontal center the text inside an element, use `text-align: center;`. And for both on a text:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid green; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="center">
  <p>I am vertically and horizontally centered.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```